# Passing Values from JSP page to Servlet page

Tags: jsp, servlets

This my JSP page here Im accepting some values and i want to send the values to Servlet and then store in DB. can any one help , is this correct approach or not... and what should be added in servlet to retrieve the values there..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="MainCSS.css" type="text/css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body background-color:blue>
        <form action="HelloServlet_new.java" method="POST">
            <div style="width:600px; margin:0 auto;">
                <span style="color:#ffffff;"><span style="font-size: 18px;"><span style="font-family: 'times new roman', times, serif;"><strong><span style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"><a href="http://My/index_new"></a> cISBN | cAttendance | cFleet |&nbsp;cHome |</span></strong></span></span></span></div>
            <div>
                <span style="font-size: 18px;"><span style="font-family: 'times new roman', times, serif;"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></span></span></div>
            <div style="width:600px; margin:0 auto;">
                Enter Your Message Here: <input type="text" name="message" value="" /><br>
                Enter the Receiver Number: <input type="text" name="receiver" value="" />
                Enter Your Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" /><br><br>
                Enter Your Number: <input type="text" name="sender" value="" /><br><br>
                Enter Your Mail_id: <input type="text" name="mailid" value="" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /><br>

            </div>

           <% request.setAttribute("message",request.getParameter("message"));%>
           <% request.setAttribute("receiver",request.getParameter("receiver"));%>
           <% request.setAttribute("name",request.getParameter("name"));%>
            <%request.setAttribute("sender",request.getParameter("sender"));%>
           <% request.setAttribute("mailid",request.getParameter("mailid"));%>

            <h2>Thank You for using Our Service !!!!!!! </h2>
            <jsp:include page="HelloServlet_new" flush="true" />
    </body>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Please remove unrelated markup. Also, have you considered using css classes? Or at least setting all the styles at once, instead of a zillion spans?

Answer (score 3):

First map your servlet in web.xml.
Within action field in form write down the URL which matches the `<url-pattern>` of the servlet provided in web.xml. For example, if it is `/urlPattern`, then you should write down:

```
<form action="urlPattern" method="POST">
```

After that within your called servlet `doPost()` you can retrieve your JSP page values by writing:

```
String message = request.getParameter("message");
String receiver = request.getParameter("receiver");
```

This is how you can get values in your servlet and after that you can write down your database transaction code to store values in database as well.

Comment: The `action` should not represent the servlet name. It should represent the servlet URL. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info for some basic Hello World examples which you may also need to read yourself.

Comment: my bad, But now edited.

Comment: You forgot the text. Plus, it is "URL pattern", not "URL pattern name".

Comment: I wrote name for the basic understanding. That's the common sense if he ever wrote servlet mapping in web.xml. He can understand what I wrote. And yeah its not "URL pattern" its <url-pattern> .

Comment: Guarav, the servlet name is not the same as the servlet URL pattern. Even more, the web.xml specifies them in entirely separate entities `<servlet-name>` and `<url-pattern>`. Doing it off as "common sense" is utter nonsense and only confusing to starters who want to do it the right way.

Comment: Yeah I know Servlet URL Pattern(That is for End User) is totally different from Servlet Name(Logical Name not Real Servlet Name). That's why I changed my code.

Comment: Your code change is fine, but you forgot to change the text. You still mention "the name of the servlet", while it should be "the URL pattern of the servlet". Also you should change `action="urlpatternName"` by `action="urlpattern"`. This all is just to avoid confusion among starters (and yourself!). That's exactly where my comment was all about.

Comment: Alright, Thanks for you advice. I will keep it in mind for next time.